# Laravel factory create without calling afterCreating callback

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-testing

While writing tests I'm creating a model using factory `$recipe = factory(Recipe::class)->create()` but the `RecipeFactory` has `afterCreating` callback that runs and adds relations every time I create a recipe.

Is there a way to skip this callback? I don't want any relations to be created.

RecipeFactory.php `afterCreating` callback

```php
$factory->afterCreating(Recipe::class, function ($recipe, Faker $faker) {
    $ingredients = factory(Ingredient::class, 3)->create();
    $recipe->ingredients()->saveMany($ingredients);
});
```

Comment: include the test code in your question, `factory->make()` might do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new state in the factory

```php
$factory->state(Recipe::class, 'withRelations', [
    //Attributes
]);
```

Then you can define the after hook on the state

```
$factory->afterCreating(Recipe::class, 'withRelations', function ($recipe, $faker) {
    $ingredients = factory(Ingredient::class, 3)->create();
    $recipe->ingredients()->saveMany($ingredients);
});
```

And remove the existing after create hook.

Now when you use the default factory - no relations will be created.

```
$recipies = factory(Recipe::class, 5)->create();
```

However if you want to create related records also - you can make use of the `withRelations` state

```
$recipiesWithRelations = factory(Recipe::class, 5)->state('withRelations')->create();
```